# undefined reference to `function' in linux C program

Tags: c, linux

I have a problem, when compile a C program in linux.
Below is the code.

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "redirect_ptr.h"

int main(void)
{
    const char *firstday = NULL;
    const char *secondday = NULL;
    get_a_day(&firstday);
    get_a_day(&secondday);
    printf("%s\t%s\n", firstday, secondday);
    return 0;
}
```

```
/* redirect_ptr.h */
#ifndef REDIRECT_PTR_H
#define REDIRECT_PTR_H

void get_a_day(const char **);

#endif
```

```
/* redirect_ptr.c */
#include "redirect_ptr.h"

static const char *msg[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

void get_a_day(const char **pp)
{
    static int i = 0;
    *pp = msg[i%7];
    i++;
}
```

I compile the code with`gcc main.c redirect_ptr.c -o main`, but an error occurs like below:

```
fanhwid@PF2KPYQX-ETA:~/clang/ptr$ gcc main.c redirect_ptr.c -o main
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQ85d3F.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `get_a_day'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `get_a_day'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can't find the reason, anyone could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure all files are in the same directory and the file names are spelled correctly, etc.?

Comment: Yes, all files are in the same directory.    ~/clang/ptr$ ls
main.c  makefile  redirect_ptr.c  redirect_ptr.h

Comment: Run this and see how far you get `gcc -Wall -c main.c -I. -o main.o && gcc -Wall -c redirect_ptr.c -o redirect_ptr.o && gcc -Wall main.o redirect_ptr.o -o main`

Comment: This should not happen if `redirect_ptr` really contains the defintion of `get_a_day` as your code shows.  Is it possible that what you posted is not what is really in your files?  For instance, you might have typed the code in `redirect_ptr.c` but forgotten to save the file before compiling.

Comment: You are right, I made a stupid mistake, did not save the file before compiling. Thanks